# Android studio 2 - emulator popup doesn't appear

Tags: android-studio

I'm new with Android studio (2.0) and android app. I downloaded android studio 2.0 two days ago and started my first application "Hello world".

When I start the application on my tablet, the application work fine and evrything seems valid.
When I start the emulator nothing happend and I don't have error messages. The emulator start but no popup windows appear. I try to understand why but without error messages it's not easy (and I'm a starter :-( )

My pc is Intel R Core CPU 3.00Ghz with 8Gb ram. Windows 7 (system type 64 bit)

I use Android studio 2.0.
The option Tools- Android - enable android ADB integration is check.

The application compile.

When I start the application with the emulator, I have this message:

> c:...\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\emulator.exe -netdelay none
>   -netspeed full -avd TAB.

After a short time, I have the message

> Waiting for target device to come online

(I cann see a process  when I start the task manager" but nothing appear and I expect a popup windows to test my app.

This is the [info from the sdk manager:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFDDq.png)

Can you help me ?

(sorry for my english, I'm Belgian)